# Export UITableView to PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am struggling with a simple snippet of code, I've dedicated a lot of time searching for this, checked forums and tried different things. I am almost there but not quite. Basically **I need to transform the contents of a UITableView to a PDF**.

The code I have right below, seems to work fine except that the user *has* to swipe the table to the end of it's content, if not that portion won't be rendered. I've scrolled the UITableView programatically but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. I am getting more and more into Quartz2D to understand this stuff further, but the client needs this fixed for yesterday :-)

```
    -(void) createPDFfromUITable:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    CGRect priorBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    CGSize fittedSize = [self.tableView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width,3000)];
    self.tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width,1800);

    CGRect pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.bounds.size.width,792);
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil);
    CGFloat pageOriginY=0;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)//for (CGFloat pageOriginY = 0; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil);
        CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        {
            CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY);
            [self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:([_resultados count]-1)] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
            CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY);

        } CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

        pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height;
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    self.tableView.bounds = priorBounds; // Reset the tableView

    NSArray     *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString    *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString    *filePathPDF = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePathPDF atomically:YES];
    [self showEmail:filePathPDF];
}
```

If you have suggestions for fixing the code I am using now, of you happen to have a whole snippet that does the whole thing, this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation where I wanted to export the data entered by user to generate a pdf report with that information.

After days of researching, I found that it wasn't a good practice to screenshot the `UITableView`.

I recommend using `CoreText` to draw it your own. Here are helper methods to do the drawing.

```
+(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw withFont:(UIFont *)font inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect
{
    if (textToDraw) {
        //    create attributed string
        CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrStr = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, 0), (CFStringRef) textToDraw);

        //    create font
        if (!font) {
            font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:12];
        }
        CFStringRef fontString = (__bridge CFStringRef)font.fontName;

        CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(fontString, font.pointSize, NULL);

        //    create paragraph style and assign text alignment to it
        CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTTextAlignmentLeft;
        CTParagraphStyleSetting _settings[] = {    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment} };
        CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(_settings, sizeof(_settings) / sizeof(_settings[0]));

        //    set paragraph style attribute
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle);

        //    set font attribute
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTFontAttributeName, fontRef);

        //    release paragraph style and font
        CFRelease(paragraphStyle);
        CFRelease(fontRef);

        // Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter

        CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrStr);


        CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

        // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
        CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
        CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
        CGPathRelease(framePath);

        // Get the graphics context.
        CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
        // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);


        // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
        // the current transform prior to drawing.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
        CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

        // Draw the frame.
        CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

        CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);



    }
}

+(void)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)from toPoint:(CGPoint)to
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();



    CGColorRef color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);


}

+(void)drawTableAt:(CGPoint)origin
     withRowHeight:(int)rowHeight
    andColumnWidth:(int)columnWidth
       andRowCount:(int)numberOfRows
    andColumnCount:(int)numberOfColumns

{
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows; i++) {

        int newOrigin = origin.y + (rowHeight*i);


        CGPoint from = CGPointMake(origin.x, newOrigin);
        CGPoint to = CGPointMake(origin.x + (numberOfColumns*columnWidth), newOrigin);

        [self drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];


    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
        int newOrigin = origin.x + (columnWidth*i);


        CGPoint from = CGPointMake(newOrigin, origin.y);
        CGPoint to = CGPointMake(newOrigin, origin.y +(numberOfRows*rowHeight));

        [self drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];


    }
}
```

So your code will be like this:

```
// Draw first page
CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612.0, 792.0);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame, nil);
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),pageFrame.size.width/screenSize.width, pageFrame.size.height/screenSize.height);
[self doTheDrawing];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```